# What does Miyamura have against cats?

Tags: yamada-and-the-7-witches

In the second OVA, Miyamura seems borderline terrified of a student wearing a maid outfit with cat ears, and indicates that he doesn't like cats.

[image: terrified Miyamura]

Why's that? What does he have against cats?